# Pythonic way to make a range list start and end where at specified values which requires the first step to be less than the step for the rest of list

Tags: python, list, indexing, range

I have some code which works but I am wondering if there is a pythonic way to do this. User requires a list of frequencies to test which will never start at 0Hz, user will input the start, stop and step values to generate a list of values to test some equipment at, what they need is a list that starts and stops at those values and not the ones python uses making a range. I have this which works but I have to fudge the start value.

**Code**

```
start = 1
stop = 100
step = 10
out = (list(range(start-start, stop+step, step)))
out[0] = start
print(out)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Is there a pythonic way to generate the list without having to use the

```
out[0] = start
```

line?

Comment: Why are you doing "start-start"?  Why don't you just use `range(start,stop,step)`?

Comment: If user enter `start` - `1` and `step` - `10`, then you have wrong list. Cause right is `[1, 11, 21, ...]`. So you can just use `range(start,stop,step)`

Comment: You understand that you expectation is wrong, though? `[1, 10, 20]` has an initial step of 9, followed by a step of 10.

Comment: @SiHa yes I get the initial step is 9, but that is what the output needs to be for the users purpose (it's weird I know but its a list of frequencies, thus it cannot start at zero).

Comment: Frequencies can absolutely start at 0, a frequency of 0 is generally taken to be a constant signal (1 everywhere).

Comment: @xdurch0 in this context testing at zero Hz produces nothing in the product, the user wants to test at the frequency they enter as the start value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using if/else in list comprehension  using just `range(start,stop,step)` :

```
out = [1 if n==0 else n for n in range(0, 100, 10)]
```

Comment: @Windy71 The pleasure is mine. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension if you want to refactor the same logic into a more pythonic approach

```
out = [start if i == 0 else i for i in range(start-start, stop+step, step)]
```